# How to uninstall Azure extensions from multiple resource groups in multiple Virtual machines?

Tags: linux, bash, azure

I have few subscriptions in Azure and at least 35 resource groups and at least 100 Virtual machines in each subscription. 
So it is 35 resource groups and 100 VM's and I wan't to delete azure extension in every VM.

Currently I am using script:

```
!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%T")
USER="user"
RESOURCEGROUPLIST="/home/$USER/resourcegroupsdev"
VMLIST="/home/$USER/vmlistdev"


echo "##################  DELETE EXTENSION ##################"
echo "Current time : $now"
cat $RESOURCEGROUPLIST | while read -r LINER
do
cat $VMLIST | while read -r LINE
do
az vm extension delete -g $LINER --vm-name $LINE -n LinuxDiagnostic --verbose
done
echo "Current time : $now"
done
```

Frequently I get this error:

```
VM 'dev-vm-test-001' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.
```

and sometimes this error:

```
Error occurred in request., SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/usr/bin/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 210, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/usr/bin/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 289, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 498, in _execute_command
    raise client_exception
ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

Deleting process takes forever - I mean - a lot of errors. No clear output, in which VM extension was deleted.

Do someone has idea how to boost process to delete extension?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your own routine - It looks like you should be responsible for printing out\keeping a list of vm extension operations errored out\completed. since you are doing the looping, not the CLI. So its your responsibility.

For the SSL handshake - no ideas; for the storage - are you having Network Security Groups blocking outbound connections (or iptables or whatever)? as they might interfere with the VM extensions, so VM extensions cannot report status. And this essentially leads to this error. You can easily verify this by logging to the portal and checking the vm in question. under the extension property it should tell you something like: "vm agent failed to report status bla-bla-bla"

i would suggest raising this at the Azure CLI 2.0 [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli). I don't think there's anything SO users can help you with here.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Yes, there are VM's reporting in Azure: "Some details about the installed extensions are unavailable. This can occur when the virtual machine is stopped or the agent is unresponsive."
And yes, I have NSG rules. I'll check them.

Comment: NSG should not block communication to azure storage on port 8443 (i believe), check VM logs `/var/logs/waagent.log` and see the exact url its trying to access